# trying to write Policy for enabling comment of posts in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, comments, acl, policy

In laravel I have a Follower table that I use to check if a User is folowing another User and also if he can comment on Posts.

The table is like this:

```
Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unsignedInteger('publisher_id')->unsigned();
            $table->unsignedInteger('follower_id')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('enable_follow')->default('1');
            $table->unique(['publisher_id', 'follower_id']);
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('publisher_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('follower_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');


        });
```

and these are the checks that I make to decide if a User can comment a Post:

```
public function canComment(User $user, Post $post)
{

    $following = Follower::where('follower_id', $user->id)->where('publisher_id', $post->user_id)->select('enable_follow')->get();

    if (!$following->isEmpty()) {

        $enabled = $following[0]['enable_follow'];

        if ($enabled != '0') {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    } else if ($following->isEmpty()) {

        return true;

    }

}
```

And this is the controller part for storing, as You can see I'm trying to authorize like this: `$this->authorize('canComment', $post[0]);`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        //on_post, from_user, body
        // define rules
        $rules = array(

            'post_id' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        $post_id = $request->input('post_id');

        $post = Post::findOrFail($post_id);   

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Response()->json($validator);
        } else {

            $this->authorize('canComment', $post);

            //prepares object to be stored in DB
            $comment = new Comment();

            $comment['user_id'] = $request->user()->id;
            $comment['post_id'] = $post_id;
            $comment['body'] = $request->input('body');
            $comment->save();
            if ($comment) {

                $comment['user_name'] = $request->user()->username;
                $comment['comment_id'] = $comment->id;
                $comment['token'] = $request->input('_token');
            }

            return Response()->json($comment);


        }
    }
```

The problem here is I get a 403 (Forbidden) error in a situation where I have `$following` empty and where following is enabled. The Policy is not working as expected.

Source code for authorize method in Gate facade:

```
public function authorize($ability, $arguments = [])
    {
        $result = $this->raw($ability, $arguments);

        if ($result instanceof Response) {
            return $result;
        }

        return $result ? $this->allow() : $this->deny();
    }
```

Maybe I am not correct returing true or false in the policy as this code expect the result to be an `instance of Response` but so what do you return to grant or deny access??

Comment: Where did you put your `canComment` method and witch laravel do you use ??

Comment: it's in the controller, don't you see it in the code?

Comment: I mean `public function canComment(User $user, Post $post) ...` witch **laravel do you use** ?

Comment: it's inside the commentPolicy class which is regularly registered. it's versione 5.1.28

Comment: Try to replace `$this->authorize('canComment', $post);` by `if( ! Gate::denies('canComment', $post){ $comment = new Comment(); ....}` in your controller !

Comment: @Maraboc `Gate::denies` is going to have the same results as `$this->authorize`, I'm not sure if that's going to help?

Comment: can't it be Gate::allows instead of !Gate::denies ?

Comment: So @Chriz74, are you saying the ability works sometimes? It's hard to tell the difference with an ability that has an internal error and one that is never running (because the current user is invalid or the policy isn't getting selected).

Comment: Gate::denies method resulted in internal server error (500). The policy is not  working no. I know that it has to work as prior to defining the policy I was checking with the same code in the controller directly without defining and calling any policy and it worked as expected. The point is I need a policy to also allow show of comment button in view. Question is, when does it denies or allow? I am returing true if check passes and false if it doesn't in the policy, does the authorize method expect to get a true or false statement or what? I also tried with 0 and 1 to no avail.

Comment: please check updated question with authorize source code

Comment: Yes you can call `Gate::allows` instead. @tdhsmith i think it will helps because `authorize` throws `AuthorizationException` that you should catch somewhere

Comment: I'm thinking the error is in returning true or false, authorize expects something else maybe but what?

Comment: I just tried to recreate the issue, something must be missing because it's not even getting into the `canComment` function.

Comment: Did You register the policy ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was putting the policy inside commentPolicy and so it expected to receive a Comment not a Post, moving it to postPolicy solved it.